# Not getting Base64 encoded data in document.ready() function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have encoded the image file using base64 encoding. After encoding i can see the value in function itself(function which encodes the image in base64.) using alert. when i try to save this value in variable, it gives "undefined" result

**here is my javascript code.**

```
 function getBase64(file) {
       var reader = new FileReader();
       var data="";
       reader.readAsDataURL(file);

       reader.onload = function () {  
        var temp=reader.result.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/,"");
        alert("inside fn:"+temp);
        return temp;

       };
       reader.onerror = function (error) {
         console.log('Error: ', error);
       };
    }    


    $(document).ready(function(){


        $("#createLAF").click(function(){

              var files = document.getElementById('panFile').files;
              if (files.length > 0) {
            alert("Outside data:"+getBase64(files[0]));
            }
```

I get the encoded value in when i hit alert(inside fn.) but don't find value in second alert i.e. alert(outside data:)

Please help to sort out the problem. My main is to convert image file into string in javascript. You  can suggest alternate solution also. Thanks in advance.

Comment: also i tried using Promise concept of javascript. still facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide some callback mechanism for your getBase64 function because the asynchronous nature of reading a file. You second alert is executed before the data is read.
You can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var getBase64 = function(file, callback) {
       var reader = new FileReader();
       var data="";
       reader.readAsDataURL(file);

       reader.onload = function () {  
         var temp = reader.result.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/,"");
         callback(temp);
       };

       reader.onerror = function (error) {
         console.log('Error: ', error);
       };
    }

    $("#createLAF").click(function(){
       var files = document.getElementById('panFile').files;
       if (files.length > 0) {
          getBase64(files[0], alertData);              
       }
    });

     var alertData = function(data){
        alert("Outside data:"+ data);
     }
});
```

Comment: getting error "alertData" is not defined.

Comment: @Nitin I assume that `getBase64` is not in document ready. With this solution it should always work

Comment: of course it is outside of ready() function. Main problem is that i'm getting output in alert, but when i try to save same output in var variable, it gives me "undefined" output.

Comment: @Nitin have you tryed the updated code?

Comment: yes i tried updated code, but is is giving me error as "alertData" is undefined.